# Regasm /codebase fails saying it cannot find the file specified when setting copylocal=true

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, regasm

I am trying to register an assembly using regasm /codebase.Everything works fine but my project requirements forces me to put the copylocal property of a referenced dll to false.When this is done regasm fails saying it cannot find the dependent dll file. everything works fine when copylocal is set to false.What could be wrong how can i fix it ? The dll always resides on a shared folder.

Comment: Please review your question and change true or false where needed for it to make sense.

Comment: [assembly]: "This tag is for assembly language programming questions not specific to any one processor." -- I changed it to [.net-assembly]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the DLL it requires is in a path that it does not know about. Without seeing your exact setup and command line code, I can't say exactly, but I would suggest trying to set your DLL path to something absolute as a test to see if the file is then found.